# Trouble outlining a multicolumn table header

Tags: tables, spacing, multicolumn

I am trying to make a table with four columns. The headers are Included features, normalization, RMSE, number. My current code:

```
\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{Tested models}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Included features & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Normalization}{RMSE}{Number} \\
\midrule
Close, volume & None & 18153.33 & 1 \\
\midrule
Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$ & None & 24292.86 & 2 \\
\midrule
Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$ & L2 & 15596.44 & 3\\
\midrule
\shortstack{Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, \\ $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd} & L2 & 18290.07 & 4\\
\midrule
\shortstack{\textbf{Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av,} \\ \textbf{tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$}} & \textbf{L2} & \textbf{12835.51} & \textbf{5} \\
\midrule
\shortstack{Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base a, \\ tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema} & L2 & 13390.82 & 6\\
\midrule
\shortstack{Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av, \\ tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd} & L2 & 13042.53 & 7\\
\midrule
\shortstack{Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av, \\ tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd} & None &  22602.08 & 8\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\bigskip
\end{table}
```

With this code, the table looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, Normalization, RMSE and Number are outlined in a weird way. I don't have a ton of experience with latex, so I'm not sure what's going on here. Am I misunderstanding how \multicolumn works?

Comment: Are "Normalization", "RMSE" and "Number" the headers of three individual columns? If so, you might want to replace `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Normalization}{RMSE}{Number} ` with `Normalization & RMSE & Number`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The normal syntax should be `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Normalization RMSE Number}`, but I don't see how each feature would be above the relevant column. `\multicolumn{n}` groups n consecutive cells in a row as a single one. I don't think that's what you want – or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @leandriis Yes! That did exactly what I wanted it to do. Not sure why I was using multicolumn there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you tried `multicolumn` when your table has 4 columns but the `multicolumn` turns that into 1+3 columns. Your code (in an `article` class) produces a table that is too wide for the textwidth.

In the MWE below I have discarded the `multicolumn` for 4 regular columns. I noted that the phrase "Close, volume" occured in every entry in the first column, so thought it would be better removed and noted elsewhere, just to simplify the appearance.

```
% multiprob.tex  SE 597728
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\cvol}{Close, volume,}
\renewcommand{\cvol}{}

\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{Tested models (with all features including Close, volume)}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
%Included features & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Normalization}{RMSE}{Number} \\
Included features & Normalization & RMSE & Number \\
\midrule
%Close, volume 
 \cvol & None & 18153.33 & 1 \\
\midrule
%Close, volume, 
 \cvol rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$ & None & 24292.86 & 2 \\
\midrule
%Close, volume, 
 \cvol rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$ & L2 & 15596.44 & 3\\
\midrule
\shortstack{\cvol rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, \\ $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd} & L2 & 18290.07 & 4\\
\midrule
\shortstack{\textbf{%Close, volume, 
 \cvol quote av, trades, tb base av,} \\ \textbf{tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema,} \\ \textbf{$stoch_k$, $stoch_d$}} & \textbf{L2} & \textbf{12835.51} & \textbf{5} \\
\midrule
\shortstack{\cvol quote av, trades, tb base a, \\ tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema} & L2 & 13390.82 & 6\\
\midrule
\shortstack{\cvol quote av, trades, tb base av, \\ tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, \\ $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd} & L2 & 13042.53 & 7\\
\midrule
\shortstack{\cvol quote av, trades, tb base av, \\ tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, \\ $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd} & None &  22602.08 & 8\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\bigskip
\end{table}


\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{Tested models}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Included features & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Normalization}{RMSE}{Number} \\
\midrule
Close, volume & None & 18153.33 & 1 \\
\midrule
Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$ & None & 24292.86 & 2 \\
\midrule
Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$ & L2 & 15596.44 & 3\\
\midrule
\shortstack{Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, \\ $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd} & L2 & 18290.07 & 4\\
\midrule
\shortstack{\textbf{Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av,} \\ \textbf{tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$}} & \textbf{L2} & \textbf{12835.51} & \textbf{5} \\
\midrule
\shortstack{Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base a, \\ tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema} & L2 & 13390.82 & 6\\
\midrule
\shortstack{Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av, \\ tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd} & L2 & 13042.53 & 7\\
\midrule
\shortstack{Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av, \\ tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd} & None &  22602.08 & 8\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\bigskip
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Some of the `shortstack` results were a bit too wide so I modified them a little bit (shortening some lines and increasing the number of lines). The result is a table that fits within the textwidth.

I have a feeling that there is a more convenient (automatic?) way of getting multiple entry lines than using `shortstack` (which I am impressed that you used); hopefully somebody else might come up with suggestions about that.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since "Normalization", "RMSE" and "Number" seem to be the headers of three individual columns, just replace `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Normalization}{RMSE}{Number}` with `Normalization & RMSE & Number` and you should get the expected otuput.

In the following MWE, I also used the `tabularx` package in order to allow for automatic linebreaks in the first column while at the same time making sure, the table fits into the textwidth. The second example shows a table with less lines, but some white space instead, as well as a different alignment in the first column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{Tested models}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}Xccc}
\toprule
Included features & Normalization & RMSE & Number \\
\midrule
Close, volume & None & 18153.33 & 1 \\
\midrule
Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$ & None & 24292.86 & 2 \\
\midrule
Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$ & L2 & 15596.44 & 3\\
\midrule
Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd & L2 & 18290.07 & 4\\
\midrule
\textbf{Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av,tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$} & \textbf{L2} & \textbf{12835.51} & \textbf{5} \\
\midrule
Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base a,  tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema & L2 & 13390.82 & 6\\
\midrule
Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av,  tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd & L2 & 13042.53 & 7\\
\midrule
Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av,  tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd & None &  22602.08 & 8\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}


\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{Tested models}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccc}
\toprule
Included features & Normalization & RMSE & Number \\
\midrule
Close, volume & None & 18153.33 & 1 \\
\addlinespace
Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$ & None & 24292.86 & 2 \\
\addlinespace
Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$ & L2 & 15596.44 & 3\\
\addlinespace
Close, volume, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd & L2 & 18290.07 & 4\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av,tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$} & \textbf{L2} & \textbf{12835.51} & \textbf{5} \\
\addlinespace
Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base a,  tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema & L2 & 13390.82 & 6\\
\addlinespace
Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av,  tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd & L2 & 13042.53 & 7\\
\addlinespace
Close, volume, quote av, trades, tb base av,  tb quote av, rsi, sma, ema, $stoch_k$, $stoch_d$, ad, cci, macd & None &  22602.08 & 8\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```